# Google Apps Script has stopped executing

Tags: execution, timing

I have been using the same code for well over a year now, have made no changes recently.  Yesterday the code worked, but today it is working intermittently, and I am dumbfounded and don't know what is the issue here.

The script keeps timing out after some 6 minutes which is the max execution time.  My spreadsheet has about 3000 lines.  Is that too much for Google?

What I did was copy the worksheet to another, deleted about 2000 lines and now it seems to work.

Why can Google handle so little, and what is happening inside of Google's little brain when it gets to 3000 lines?

Is there any way to solve this?

The beginning of my code is as follows:

```js
function onEdit(){
  
  var TargetSheet = 'Geroba';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List20")
  var dataP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ListP")
  var sname = ss.getName();  // Lists

  Logger.log(sname);
  Logger.log(TargetSheet);
 
  if (sname == TargetSheet) {
  
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
    if(activeCell.getColumn() == 10 && activeCell.getRow() > 4){

      Browser.msgBox(TargetSheet);
    
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();  // Clears Series
      activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearContent().clearDataValidations();  // Clears Code
      activeCell.offset(0, 3).clearContent().clearDataValidations();  // Clears Material
      activeCell.offset(0, 4).clearContent();  // Clears Extra (for Standard)
      activeCell.offset(0, 5).clearContent();  // Clears Item description
      activeCell.offset(0, 6).clearContent();  // Clears Weight (kg)
      activeCell.offset(0, 7).clearContent();  // Clears RAL
      activeCell.offset(0, 8).clearContent();  // Clears Qty
      activeCell.offset(0, 9).clearContent();  // Clears Price Quoted from
      activeCell.offset(0, 11).clearContent();  // Clears Unit Price
      activeCell.offset(0, 12).clearContent();  // Clears Price after discount
      activeCell.offset(0, 21).clearContent();  // Clears "Standard" from Drawing Status column
      activeCell.offset(0, 22).clearContent();  // Clears Design link pathway
       
      var CategoriesS2 = datass.getRange(2, 3, 1, 28).getValues();  // row, column, numRows, numColumns
    
      var makeIndex2 = CategoriesS2[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 3;
    
      if(makeIndex2 != 0) {
    
          var validationRangeSeries2 = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex2, 40);   //  datass.getLastRow());
          var validationRuleSeries2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRangeSeries2).setAllowInvalid(true).build();
          activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRuleSeries2);
      
      }
    
    }
    
  }
  
  }
```

Comment: Did you encounter any specific errors? If the script is encountering timeouts, it can be from many reasons like external HTTP takes too long to respond, your code getting stuck in a loop and many other reasons. It will be extremely difficult to troubleshoot the exact nature of your problem without more information. If you have Logging setup via Google Cloud, share that as well. As for lines of code: I have had much bigger projects running on app script; I have not noticed any issues due to the size of the project so far.

Comment: I have encountered no errors whatsoever, just timeouts.  I am not sure what you mean by the external HTTP taking too long to respond.  I do know that when I saved the file, deleted 2000 lines, it worked fine.  How do I set up logging via Google Cloud

Comment: You can go to your project settings and add the project ID of a Google Cloud project that you have created. Then all errors will be available in Logging. Also, if possible, add some `console.log` in your code to trace its execution. This will help you understand this functions in your code is taking too long. You can also check `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` to time your functions.